# How to Extract a number between two brackets in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a log file that I am trying to extract a number from that is between 2 brackets then export that data to a CSV. Here is the code that I currently have. It successfully pulls the date, time and the message along with pulling the loading length except I don't want it to have the word length or have the brackets around the numbers. I just want the number in a separate column. I am only concerned with the "Loading length" number don't need any of the runout numbers. Here is also an example of the

log file:

```
02/13/2023 05:20:15.371 [S]0 Degree Long Feedback Spring Measurement. Loading Length[0.7357], Positive RunOut[0.0531], Negative Runout[-0.0377]
02/13/2023 05:20:15.434 [S]Status Message (M09): Feedback Spring Runout Meets Tolerance
02/13/2023 05:20:16.729 [S]Status Message (M09): 
02/13/2023 05:20:19.973 [S]Status Message (M09): 
02/13/2023 05:20:21.955 [S]Waiting for (M5187==1) in Position Bit
02/13/2023 05:20:22.501 [S]Waiting for (M5187==1) in Position Bit
02/13/2023 05:20:22.719 [E]Vision Correction 5 Offset. XOffset[-0.0121], YOffset[-0.0167]
02/13/2023 05:20:22.719 [S]Vision Correction 5 Success. XOffset[-0.0121], YOffset[-0.0167]
02/13/2023 05:20:22.766 [S]Status Message (M09): Vision Correction Success
02/13/2023 05:20:24.404 [S]Waiting for (M5187==1) in Position Bit
02/13/2023 05:20:26.026 [S]Status Message (M09): 
02/13/2023 05:20:29.193 [S]Waiting for (M5187==1) in Position Bit
02/13/2023 05:20:29.739 [S]Waiting for (M5187==1) in Position Bit
02/13/2023 05:20:29.911 [E]Vision Correction 5 Offset. XOffset[-0.0024], YOffset[0.0013]
02/13/2023 05:20:29.911 [S]Vision Correction 5 Success. XOffset[-0.0024], YOffset[0.0013], BallRadius[0.0454]
02/13/2023 05:20:29.973 [S]Status Message (M09): Vision Correction Success
02/13/2023 05:20:31.611 [S]Waiting for (M5187==1) in Position Bit
02/13/2023 05:20:33.015 [S]Reading Long Feedback Spring Length[0.7370], Upper Range[0.7470], Lower Range[0.7270]
02/13/2023 05:20:33.015 [S]90 Degree Long Feedback Spring Measurement. Loading Length[0.7357], Positive RunOut[0.0431], Negative Runout[-0.0478]
```

**Current Code**

```
Get-content J:\datalogs\DMDiagnosticData.log| ForEach {
    $line = $_.Trim()
    If ($line.Contains('Degree Long Feedback Spring Measurement')) {
        $str = $line.Split(' ')
        $props = [ordered]@{
            Date = $str[0]
            Time = $str[1]
            Message = $_.SubString(0,$line.IndexOf('Loading Length')).Replace($str[0],'').Replace($str[1],'').Trim()
            Length = $str[9]
        }
        New-Object PsObject -Property $props
    }
}
```

[image]

I would like the output for example to be:

```
Date       Time         Message                                        Length
----       ----         -------                                        ------
02/13/2023 13:10:11.513 [S]0 Degree Long Feedback Spring Measurement.  0.7360
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might help:

```
Get-content J:\datalogs\DMDiagnosticData.log | ForEach-Object {
    If ($_.Contains('Degree Long Feedback Spring Measurement')) {
        $str = $_.Split(' ')
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Date    = $str[0]
            Time    = $str[1]
            Message = [regex]::Match($_, '(?<=\s)\[\w].+\.(?=\sLoading Length)').Value
            Length  = [regex]::Match($str[9], '(?<=\[)[^]]+').Value
        }
    }
}
```

I have changed how to obtain the `Message` property using regex, seems easier this way though you can still use what you currently have. See https://regex101.com/r/8vM8lm/2 for details on that one.

As for getting the numbers between brackets, see this link https://regex101.com/r/o5wAmh/1 for details.

---

Here is a different way of doing it with a single regex that captures all the values of interest. It also uses a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) to read your file with `-Regex` flag.

```bash
switch -File J:\datalogs\DMDiagnosticData.log -Regex {
    '((?:\d{2}/){2}\d{4})\s((?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\.\d{3})\s(\[\w].+\.)\sLoading Length\[([^]]+)' {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Date    = $Matches[1]
            Time    = $Matches[2]
            Message = $Matches[3]
            Length  = $Matches[4]
        }
    }
}
```

And the regex details here: https://regex101.com/r/HYh6W2/1.

Comment: @UselessCoder this is a new requirement. please ask a new question for this. if this answer helped solving the initial question please consider accepting it